# Overload resolution ambiguity on Int.toBigDecimal in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I want to convert integers to bigDecimals. However, it seems that IntelliJ'Idea sees twice the definition for the toBigDecimal().

when trying on the REPL I get this error:

```
12.toBigDecimal()
error: overload resolution ambiguity: 
@SinceKotlin @InlineOnly public inline fun Int.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
@SinceKotlin @InlineOnly public inline fun Int.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
```

Meanwhile it is fine using Strings:

```
"12".toBigDecimal()
res1: java.math.BigDecimal = 12
```

I am using Kotlin version 1.3.61 (JRE 1.8.0_232-b09)

I am very confused and I don't know waht to look after. any pointers?

Comment: Failed to reproduce. Does it happen only in the REPL? Can you please file an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with a sample project and IDE logs? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce it anymore, definitely a bug in the IDE. It sounds unhelpful but I can't provide any logs either... :/

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced the same issue and managed to solve it.

Just right click on the error and select ignore in compile and it will compile and run fine.